# Angular http GET 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cordova, lumen

I'm implementing another function in an application (made with angular), I call an API (made with Lumen) and it returns a 405 error whem i tried in local and "XMLHttpRequest cannot load Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)" when i tried on the server. I read about CORS but it's already implemented, I think if it isn't none of others functions would work.

Another thing, if I make the call with Advanced Rest Client it works fine :(

sorry about my english, i don't speak it so much.

function on application

```
$scope.agencias = [];

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    //url: 'http://api-beta.grupoaldorf.com.mx/agencias/',
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/agencias/',
    headers: agenciaMazda.headers
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.agencias = response.data;
    console.log("regreso del http");
    console.log($scope.agencias);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    //callback(false);
});
```

route on web.php

```
$app->get('agencias','CitasController@agenciasDisponibles');
```

controller in CitasController.php

```
public function agenciasDisponibles(Agencia $agencia){
    $fabricante = $this->request->header('Aldorf-App');
    $disponibles = Agencia::where('fabricante', $fabricante)->where('mostrar', 1)->select(['codigo', 'nombre'])->get();
    return $disponibles;
}
```

Comment: You are sending custom Header agenciaMazda check on your backend to allow those custom headers first and check if that resolve the cors problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved it, it was really dumb, i added a slash at the end of the uri xD it had to be "http://localhost:8000/agencias" instead of "http://localhost:8000/agencias/"